# Calling index.js method from alloy.js in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm able to call the variables and functions of alloy.js class file from index.js but I want to call a method from alloy.js of index.js. How to get it done? I tried to decalre require(index.js or index) but in vain and it pops me an error and crash the application.

```
index.js 

 todo_method{

}

alloy.js

//call todo_method(); of index.js
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

**index.js**

```
$.sayHello = function() { // Or you can use `exports.sayHello` too
    console.log("Hello");
};
```

**alloy.js**

```
var index = Alloy.createController("index");
    index.sayHello(); // Call function defined in index.js
```